# Lucene searching and ranking with topdocs

Tags: java, lucene

I have managed to create an index using some supplied Java code with Lucene and indexed 9 XML files successfully.  I now have to modify another supplied Java file to search the index.  I am able to output the number of hits, but I need to further modify the output so that when you submit a query it outputs the top ten results in the following format:-

```
Ranking: 0. Filename: .xml  FilePath: c:/folder/movie.xml Score: 0.5
```

I'm trying to create a for loop, but none of the examples I have tried seem to work.  This is my first venture with both Java and Lucene, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class LuceneSearch {

    public int n = 0;
//String fileName;
/*searchIndex is the method involved with initiating Searching the Index 
via the standardanalyzer by iterating through and using Hits for the results*/
    public static void searchIndex(String searchString) throws IOException, ParseException {
        String fieldContents = "summary";//current field name to search for. Each text item field name= 'contents'
      String fileName = "filename";
      String filePath = "filepath";

        Directory directory = FSDirectory.getDirectory("/Users/Jac/Documents/index/");
        //get index location
        //initiate reader and searcher classes
        IndexReader indexReader = IndexReader.open(directory);
        IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);
        //initiate standardanalyzer
        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
        //parse the query contents field with queryparser
        QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser(fieldContents, analyzer);
        //get user query string
        Query query = queryParser.parse(searchString.toLowerCase());
        //Initiate HITS class and utilise methods

       TopDocs hits = indexSearcher.search(query,null,10);
       System.out.println("Searching for '" + searchString.toLowerCase() + "'");
       //Hits hits = indexSearcher.search(query);
       System.out.println("Number of hits: " + hits.totalHits);



System.out.println("Searching XML Tag Element '" + searchString.toLowerCase() + "'");
  System.out.println("Number of hits: " + hits.totalHits);          
     for(ScoreDoc scoreDoc : hits.scoreDocs) {
   //     Document doc = IndexSearcher.doc(scoreDoc.doc);
            System.out.println("Ranking: ");
  //      System.out.println(doc.get("fullpath"));
    }      


  System.out.println("***Search Complete***");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
```

Comment: what exactly is not working? you don't get an output or are there some informations missing? this doesn't looks that bad for me

Comment: All working now Dom, I wasn't referencing document correctly to pick up ranking details.  Thanks for getting in touch.

Comment: what was the problem? can you provide a solution just for others